# UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered is deprecated; what should I do, instead?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, deprecated

I'm trying to create a `UIBarButtonItem` like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *discardButton =
   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"edit-document.button.discard", "Discard Changes button")
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(discardButtonAction:)];
```

However, I notice that `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` is now deprecated. What should I do, instead?

Comment: Ok, What is your question?

Comment: just use a non-deprecated style.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` instead.