# UIBarButton Deprecated in IOS 8.0

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

After changing the deployment target from 7.1 to 8.2, I just got a warning telling me that UIBarButton is deprecated.

Here is the code that I use:

```
UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(nextButton)],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil], nil];
self.numberOfGuestsTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
```

Is there anything that I can use instead of **UIBarButtonItem**

[image: error]

Comment: Use `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` instead of `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered`.

Comment: @BensonTommy and if i need from my code to work on iOS 7 and iOS 8 i need to check wether th os is 7 or 8 using this     if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) statement right ?

Comment: I don't think so,they are all available from iOS2.0 and above.

Comment: @BensonTommy thanks !!

Comment: how we can change the textColor of the UIbarbutton

Comment: [item setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered is deprecated; what should I do, instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210776/uibarbuttonitemstylebordered-is-deprecated-what-should-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`UIBarButtonItem` is not deprecated - `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` is. Just use `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` or `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone` instead.

As of iOS 7, the style of bar buttons has changed to a more flat form. That's why `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` is no longer available - it just looks like a `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` button. With `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone`, the text will be bold instead of regular.

Comment: can you take a look for my question on [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788537/accessing-the-setmethod-of-a-property-in-ios) ??